# jquery submitting a form

Tags: jquery, submit

**THANKS to all for replying.
SOLUTION found: I used a DIV instead of a FORM and serialized every INPUT inside it.**

**CURRENT FIDDLE CODE:** http://jsfiddle.net/MyBZC/

The form:

```
<form id="sfn" name="sfn">
       <input name="datasource" type="hidden" value="TDA">
       <input name="staticfields" type="hidden" value="">
       <input name="returnfield" type="hidden" value="Complaintinformation_ID">
       <input  name="returnid" type="hidden" value="Complaintinformation_ID">
    eCI ID:<input  class="nostyle" type="text" name="id" id="Complaintinformation_ID" style="width:150px;"/> 
    Complaint number: <input  class="nostyle" type="text" name="ecin" id="ecin" style="width:150px;"/>
</form>
```

The JQuery:

```
var ds= $("#sfn").serializeArray();
alert(ds);
```

**alerting ds gives me an empty alert box. Can it be the serializeArray() isn't working because this html form is actually inside another form tag?**

Unedited real (longer) html output is this:

```
    <form id="searchform_srcSupplier" name="searchform_srcSupplier">
        <input name="datasource" type="hidden" value="DEACSQL10_BPCS_DATA">
        <input name="from" type="hidden" value="BPCS_AVM">
        <input name="where" type="hidden" value="Partner_ID='122'">
        <input name="componentname" type="hidden" value="srcSupplier">
        <input name="staticstrings" type="hidden" value="Supplier address">
        <input name="staticfields" type="hidden" value="LTRIM(RTRIM(VNDAD1))+'<br>'+LTRIM(RTRIM(VNDAD2))+'<br>'+LTRIM(RTRIM(VCITY))+'<br>'+LTRIM(RTRIM(VPOST))+' '+LTRIM(RTRIM(VSTATE))">

        <input class="nostyle" name="returnfield" type="hidden" value="VNDNAM">
        <input class="nostyle" name="returnid" type="hidden" value="VENDOR_id">
        <table ><tr>

            <td>
                Supplier ID: 
            </td>
            <td>
                <input  class="nostyle" type="text" name="VENDOR" id="VENDOR" style="width:150px;"/>
            </td>

            <td>
                Supplier name: 
            </td>
            <td>
                <input  class="nostyle" type="text" name="VNDNAM" id="VNDNAM" style="width:150px;"/>
            </td>

                </tr><tr>

    </tr>
    </table>
    </form>
```

(I already tried removing the table from the form)

**CURRENT FIDDLE CODE:** http://jsfiddle.net/MyBZC/

Comment: try alerting length of ds so that you may know if anything is serialized or not

Comment: @Abu: length is 0 (zero). also if I log 'ds' in console, it just gives me a blank line. not even [object]

Comment: can you try `serialize()` I don't know what's the difference but plz try it and also let me know

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this: **Working Demo** http://jsfiddle.net/tFSdq/ **or** http://jsfiddle.net/bnTLR/

You need to serialise the input inside container. not the container itself

Hope this fits the need `:)`

P.S. don't forget to click `click me man` button to get alert in second demo using `serialize` and `.serializeArray`.

**code**

```
var ds= $("#sfn input").serializeArray();
alert(ds);​
```

**Further see 3 images below** which shows what these 2 alerts displays on the values entered.
 [image]

**Image 2**

[image]

**Image 3**

[image]

Comment: @PragneshChauhan `:)` Awesome!!

Comment: I tried this; it's not working. this is my current code: 
http://jsfiddle.net/MyBZC/

Comment: also; its a FORM in another bigger FORM, is that an issue?

Comment: I see it (and believe it) but with my code (jsfiddle.net/MyBZC), it's not working :( I don't get it at all... it should be working

Comment: Lol **click** on the click me button hope you are clicking the button ? @PoeHaH `:))`

Comment: @PoeHaH Wait lemme add the **working screenshot** and how it behaves at my end, hope your JQ alert is not turned off?I have updated my post above `:))`

Comment: Thanks for all your work. I ended up using a DIV instead of a FORM and serialize all INPUTs inside this div. This did the trick for me.

Answer (score 1):

add `#id` like this

```
var ds= $("#sfn").serializeArray();
alert(ds);
```

`serializeArray()` and `serialize()` both are working for me please check [myfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pintu31/FYVvq/1/)

Comment: I'm sorry, it was a typo in my code. the # selector is there, but it's not working.

Answer (score 1):

Like you have already figured out, `serializeArray()` does not work on nested forms since it is *illegal* HTML as stated in the [jQuery docs](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/serializeArray):

> Note that **serializeArray()** only works on form elements, using this
>   method on another element will not work. Also, this method will not
>   give any results on nested forms, which are illegal in HTML anyway.

You may need to work with `serialize()` as stated by jhonraymos or use Tas_innit's method.

Comment: @PoeHaH bruv, serialise is working see here: http://jsfiddle.net/bnTLR/ my reply above as well `:)` hope it helps you! Hope you are clicking the `button` to get the alerts.

Comment: yes I am.. I SEE it's working in this code, but whenever I ADAPT my code to this example, it's not working

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this: 
http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/serializeArray

it is written over here that...."this method will not give any results on nested forms, which are illegal in HTML anyway"